# Android Switching between Dark/Light themes not working

Tags: android, android-dark-theme, android-darkmode

I am working on an Android project where I need to support switching between Dark/Light themes based on system setting preference.

I have changed App Theme from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` to `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar`.

I am using this API on Application `onCreate()`
`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);`

App theme is getting updated only when I restart app but does not update when I am within the app when theme is changed from system setting.

Am I missing any config changes?

Comment: Can you add your manifest.xml?

Comment: @user14678216 I will not be able to provide the entire Android Manifest file. Are you looking for any specific part in the manifest like Activity configChanges tag?

Comment: Yes the configChanges

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".settings.SettingsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>

This is for one of the activities.

Comment: @Prashanth Ever found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue lies with the `android:configChanges` tag. This is because the activity needs to be recreated when the theme is changed. You will have to remove the tag and use `onSavedInstanceState` to save the state of your current activity.

Comment: Activity restarts even without removing that tag. Tested after removing the tag, Activity still restarts but theme is not getting updated.